# Supporting mouse shortcuts when dispatching a new MouseEvent in Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox, cross-browser, mouseevent

Not all clickable areas in our UI can be expressed as `<a href>` - we have complex dom elements with custom click handlers, such as table rows.

Here is a contrived example of what we do - https://jsfiddle.net/yb5me94t/

It works as expected in Chrome v90 and Safari v14, but not Firefox v88. Normal click works in FF, but once you use any of the mouse shortcuts the event fails to do anything. This isn't unique to environment, I was able to reproduce in a private React app && on codepen - the browser is definitely the issue.

Any idea how we can support mouse shortcuts like this in Firefox?